# не могу понять как реализовать файловую систему sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Не хочу сделать на сайте для пользователей файловую систему папка+файл 
например пользователь создал папку "home" в ней папка "user" и так далее в этих папка могут быть файлы 
если делать так ток как в итоге найти родителя

```html
|id|idUser|path|file|
| 1|1     |home|    |
| 2|2     |home|1.jpg|
| 1|1     |grou|2.jpg|
```

как сделать так чтобы было понятно где родительская папка, а где нет
использую php и mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется ответ лежит на поверхности. Для каждой папки необходимо указывать ID родителя. Если он `NULL`  то считаем эту папку созданной в корне нашей "файловой системы".
Ну и стоит внести признак отличающий папку от файла.  Таблица выглядела бы следующим образом:

```html
|id|idUser|name |isFile|ParentID|
| 1|1     |home |false |NULL    |
| 2|2     |1.jpg|true  |1       |
| 3|1     |2.jpg|true  |NULL    |
| 4|1     |usr  |false |1       |
| 5|1     |5.jpg|true  |4       |
```